# mocha-phantomjs xunit reporter and file output not working

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

using 
$mocha-phantomjs -R xunit -f outputFile.xml myPage.html

----> this is generating a console output in xml format but not writing in the output file.

On the other hand :

$mocha-phantomjs -R json -f outputFile.json myPage.html

-----> this is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so this thing has been previously resolved as a part of issues in github repo of mocha-phantomjs. Here is the link [Go To Issue](https://github.com/metaskills/mocha-phantomjs/issues/114)